# A:Hover problem in chrome

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having a problem with styling my links for chrome, yet it works in safari.

I have my normal styling like this:

```
a:link {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
    color:#c40000;
} etc....
```

Now this works on some of the links but it doesn't work on them all, i can only get it to work on the other ones by drilling down in to the div.. example:

```
.col a:hover {
    color:#c40000;
}
```

I have searched but haven't found any solutions apart from setting styles for every div that has a link in it... which seems stupid.

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE - Just checked on my laptop and this is an OSX issue, works fine on chrome on my vista laptop just not on my iMac ;/

Comment: Double and triple check your root level css for typos. I'm not saying you haven't checked - I'm saying check again anyway... :P

Comment: try it with FF, if you get the same result there, install firebug and check where the CSS rules are coming from.

Comment: Double and triple checked and ran through a css validator ;]

Comment: @roe works fine on FF.. Thanks for the help anyway =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
a:hover {
    color:#c40000 !important;
}
```

The `!important` keyword will override any previous styles.

Comment: No luck ;/ I am not really sure why it is doing it. Thanks anyway ;]